# How to keep a reference to component created within a loop?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I'm learning Svelte and I'm trying to make a component (a color palette). I blindly went for a solution where each `ColorSelector` (the color div you click on) is a Svelte component. (I'd gladly take an example where no child components are used)

I export a `selected` property in the ColorSelector.svelte component file. I'd like to set that property to `false` on every ColorSelectors instantiated when one of them is clicked except on the one that has been clicked.

However, I'm struggling to find how to keep a reference to an instantiated component in a loop. How can I achieve this?

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import { Colors, Color } from "./modules/colors";
  import ColorSelector from "./ColorSelector.svelte";

  const DEFAULT_COLOR = Colors.LIGHT_WHITE;
  let selectedColor:Color = DEFAULT_COLOR;

function handleClick(event, i) {
  selectedColor = event.detail.color;
  // When clicked set ColorSelector.selected = false on evert ColorSelectors 
  // except the one that has been clicked
}
</script>

<div>
  {#each Object.values(Colors) as color, i}
    <ColorSelector on:selected={handleSelect} color={color}></ColorSelector>
  {/each}
</div>

<style>
  div {
    display: flex;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep a reference to a component inside a loop you could use `bind:this` to an array. Have a look at this question [Svelte how to bind div inside each lop to obtain a reference using this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70787043/svelte-how-to-bind-div-inside-each-lop-to-obtain-a-reference-using-this/70787472#70787472)

To be able to set the property on the component the [option](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-options) must be activated with `<svelte:options accessors={true}/>` Here's a solution with the data flow I assume you were trying to build >> [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/b764e9cee24b417c8f2e2c0181420f0c?version=3.46.3)

```
<script>
    import ColorSelector from './ColorSelector.svelte'
    import {Colors} from './Colors'
    const DEFAULT_COLOR = Colors.LIGHT_WHITE;

    let selectedColor = DEFAULT_COLOR
    let colorSelectors = []

    function handleSelect(e,i) {
        selectedColor = e.detail.color
        colorSelectors.forEach(cS => cS.selected=false)
        colorSelectors[i].selected = true
    }

</script>

<p><b>{selectedColor}</b></p>

<div>
    {#each Object.values(Colors) as color, i}
    <ColorSelector {color} bind:this={colorSelectors[i]}
                           selected={color === DEFAULT_COLOR ? true : false}
                           on:selected="{(e) => handleSelect(e,i)}"/>
    {/each}
</div>

<style>
    div {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
</style>
```

[ColorSelector.svelte]

```
<svelte:options accessors={true}/>

<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
    
    export let color, selected  

    function handleClick() {
        dispatch('selected', {
            color
        });
    }
</script>

<div class="color-selector"
         class:selected
         style:background={color}            
         on:click={handleClick}
    ></div>

<style>
    .color-selector {
        flex-basis: 200px;
        flex-grow: 1;
        height: 100px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .selected {
        border: 5px solid black;
    }
</style>
```

But I think these features are not really needed to build the selector nor is the `selected = true/false` flag because only the one selected color is important.
Here's a simpler solution with and without a component [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/76eefe5569744ea88960a79b65eb4329?version=3.46.3)

```
<script>
    import ColorSelector from './ColorSelector.svelte'
    import {Colors} from './Colors'
    const DEFAULT_COLOR = Colors.LIGHT_WHITE;
    let selectedColor = DEFAULT_COLOR;
</script>

<p><b>{selectedColor}</b></p>

<div>
    {#each Object.values(Colors) as color, i}
    <div class="color-selector"
             class:selected-color={selectedColor === color}
             style:background={color}            
             on:click={() => selectedColor = color}
        ></div>
    {/each}
</div>

<hr>

<div>
    {#each Object.values(Colors) as color, i}
    <ColorSelector {color} bind:selectedColor />
    {/each}
</div>

<style>
    div {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .color-selector {
        flex-basis: 200px;
        flex-grow: 1;
        height: 100px;
    }
    .selected-color {
        border: 5px solid black;
    }
    hr {
        margin: 3rem;
    }
</style>
```

[ColorSelector.svelte]

```
<script>
    export let color, selectedColor
</script>

<div class="color-selector"
         class:selected-color={selectedColor === color}
         style:background={color}            
         on:click={() => selectedColor = color}
    ></div>

<style>
    .color-selector {
        flex-basis: 200px;
        flex-grow: 1;
        height: 100px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .selected-color {
        border: 5px solid black;
    }
</style>
```